# PXE boot via off-site TFTP server

Tags: proxy, pxe, tftp

I would like to PXE boot from a TFTP server that is not on my local network. The server is running in a cloud VM.

Is it possible to specify the remote server's IP without utilizing DHCP?

If not, what would the simplest pass-through method be to proxy requests via another working PC on the local subnet?

Answer (score 2):

[DHCP is an element of PXE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment). There is no PXE without DHCP.

There are older methods of network booting, such as DHCP's direct ancestors [BOOTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_Protocol) and [RARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RARP), but then, those are also unrelated to PXE other than the shared ancestry.

I'd say the simplest way to do what you want is to run a DHCP server on the "other working PC on the local subnet". You likely already have a DHCP server, but if it's just the one within your Internet modem/router/gateway, it's probably not very featureful. You'll thus get other benefits by replacing it.

The two standard options are [ISC DHCP](https://www.isc.org/downloads/dhcp/) and [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html). Most of the instructions you'll find on PXE assume ISC DHCP, and it's fairly easy to set up, but `dnsmasq` is easier in some ways and also gets you a DNS server suitable for managing a small LAN.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at [ipxe](http://ipxe.org/).

It is possible to configure ipxe to take a specific IP address and then boot from the internet.

Their [examples](http://ipxe.org/examples) section is pretty extensive, I'm cannot guarantee you'll find exactly what you need, but you can probably work from there. There's documentation on how to build your own `pxeboot.0` kernel, and even a boot ROM for your NIC.

Comment: wow, that looks AWESOME. I'll see if my ROM can be flashed on this particular machine. Opens up a lot of possibilities...

Comment: @lalalalalalalambda Well, the most interesting thing, is that you can boot from a server on the internet. It's what I use for a very sophisticated boot option. Even the menus are loaded from the server. So, no need for updating the USB pendrive...